dialog flow cx using Image tag for rich content
I want to apply custom CSS like width and height to image which is not possible if I use image rich content it renders the image with original width and height
    {
      "richContent": [
          {
             "type": "image",
             "rawUrl": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
             "accessibilityText": "image"
          }
  ]}

so I found out Image can also be rendered using html rich content as shown below
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "html",
        "html": "<img src='https://example.com/image.jpg' alt='Image Description' style='width: 150px; height: auto;'>"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

when I embedded this content in dialog flow cx custom payload response as shown below

I don't see the src value in html chatbot response please refer the below snapshot

how can we add custom css in dialog flow since everything is so tightly wrapped in shadow dom? and why are we not seeing the src value in the above way
for more details  below is dialogflow documentation  for html response type https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger/fulfillment#html_response_type
